# HTML in Rails, aligning a link and a back button from different files

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `new.html.erb` and a `_form.html.erb`

How do you align a button and a link if the **back** link is in the `new.html.erb` file while, a submit button would be in the `_form.html.erb`?

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', project_path %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@trip) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :project_name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <div class="top-buffer">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is there a rails way to align the back and the button together? What would be the conventional way?

Should I just simply put the back button in the `_form.html.erb`? Will this affect anything in the long run?

Comment: What do you actually mean by align the buttons? Vertically? Horizontally? It completely depends on your CSS.

Comment: @max horizontally... It would be nice to have a back link and a submit button next to each other, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**_form.html.erb** is what is called a partial. Partials allow you to remove unnecessary duplication of code. They help breaking the rendering process into more manageable chunks **without** changing functionality.

To answer all of your questions, ask yourself why you are using a partial. If this is to remove duplication then go ahead and move the back button inside _form.html.erb.

Now, if you could provide some css we could actually help you to center those buttons.

#### **UPDATE**

I have just realised you are using bootstrap. In this case try updating your link to this...

`<%= link_to 'Back', project_path, class: "btn btn-primary pull-left" %>`

and see if it solves your problem.

This is what I got ...

[image: simple]

... and it seems more or less aligned to me.

Comment: Ahhh, I knew what my issue was... I had a div container within the _form.html.erb so outside of that was the back button. Fix now! Thanks!